# Not understanding Fisher Information

Tags: statistics

I have this very simple homework problem:

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample from the $\operatorname{Bernoulli}(p)$ distribution. Find the Fisher information $I(p)$.

I freely admit that my problem is I don't comprehend what a *Fisher Information* is.  (Incidentally, is there a difference between *Fisher Information* and *Fisher Information Matrix*?)  This is what I have thus far.

Since a Bernoulli Distribution is a Binomial Distribution, the samples are independent and individual.  Since the likelihood function is $\mathbb{L} = \prod_{i=1}^n f(X_i\mid\theta)$ and the log likelihood is $\ell = \log(\mathbb{L}(\theta))$ this yields $I(\theta) = \mathbb{E}\{\mathbb{\ell}\,'(\theta)\mathbb{\ell}\,'(\theta)^T\} = -\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{\ell}\,''(\theta))$.

However, I do not know if I'm on the right path.  I'd appreciate insight.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Information matrix is the generalization of Information function for multiple parameters (or a vector parameter). Here you only need the definition $I(p)=E_p\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\ln f_p(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\right]^2$, which equals $nE_p\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\ln f_p(X_1)\right]^2$ as $X_i$'s are i.i.d.

Comment: @StubbornAtom thank you.  I have a couple of questions.  First, I had thought I was needing the definition.  What I have above is a copy from the textbook of, what I thought, was the definition.  It is different than yours.  How close am I?  Second, you have the notation of $[ ]^2$.  Is this indicating a matrix raised to a power, or second partial derivative?

Comment: $I(p)$ here is not a matrix; it is simply a function of $p$. With the second derivative, an equivalent formula here is $I(p)=-nE_p\left[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial p^2}\ln f_p(X_1)\right]$.

Comment: Your question is answered at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Single-parameter_Bernoulli_experiment, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2919044/321264

Comment: @StubbornAtom thank you again.  I believe I understand it better now.